# Function call as parameter

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, function-pointers

I am designing a small threading framework, and i'd like that threading framework to be as transparent as possible to the final code, in such a way that it barely affects the syntax of linear code. I've thought out most of the pieces, yet something is giving me an itch: How to define a parameter so function calls are NOT resolved until i've succesfully switched out their context into a new thread?

The idea:

```
var myTask = new Transaction();
myTask < xyz.abc();
myTask < xyz.def();
...some more code...
var result = waitfornext myTask;
```

In essence, myTask would grab the abc() and def() calls and pipeline them into a Thread, then the waitfor operator would block until myTask's pipeline has finished and code that depended on abc() and def() can continue. In a manner of speaking this IS .Net's await/async model, but i'd like to re-do it my own way so it can be used across all .Net versions, and possibly be ported to Java/XYZ languages.

The problem:
The abc() and def() calls would be evaluated by the compiler BEFORE feeding their return values to the < operator, what i really want though, is to be able to have those function calls fed to the operator so i can defer execution of them until the pipeline thread is ready to do so.

The rationale:
Unlike the async/await model, you wouldn't have to modify your methods so they can be async'ed, and you could use any method with the transactioned methods anyway. Another advantage would be that with erasing a couple lines your code would be back to being linear (Not that the async model doesn't have this advantage, but it's worth mentioning it anyways)

Any ideas?

Comment: Delegates? Lambdas? What does this have that the Task Parallel Library doesn't have, though?

Comment: I have my motives, the fact that it already exists should never stop you from wanting to recreate it.

Comment: I'm totally down with re-inventing the wheel when you want a better wheel, or want a better understanding of how wheels work. You've a very unusual/ un-C# approach here that I don't understand though.

Comment: Think of it being like a lightweight threading mechanism, one that is thought from the ground up to allow you to parallelize algorithms in the easiest way possible. I don't want to tie it into .Net/C# because i have plans for this to be a cross-runtime thing, something i can later port into other languages, keeping the syntax as similar as possible. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `xyz.abc()` as the parameter, which will be evaluated then and there, instead pass **something that can *become* `xyz.abc()`**, and modify the target method to do the 'becoming':

Change

```
var evaluatedNow = SomeMethod(GetParameterValue());

...

object SomeMethod(SomeType value)
{
    // Do something with value
}
```

To

```
var evaluatedLater = SomeMethod(() => GetParameterValue());

...

object SomeMethod(Func<SomeType> valueGetter)
{
    SomeType value = valueGetter();
    // Do something with value
}
```

Comment: I was wondering about that kind of system, but i thought i had to force the developer/user to wrap the method in a class (Kind of like runnable on java). One question though? Will the Func hold all the parameters? In other words, is () => xyz.abc(myParam) valid as a Func anyways?

Comment: If the compiler can work out which method you mean (ie it's in scope), you don't need a wrapping class. And you can have any expression you like after the `=>` as long as it has the right type (so any method invocation that returns the right type is OK).

Comment: Note that `()=>xyz.abc(myParam)` captures `myParam` so even if it's a value-type (e.g. an integer), if it changes after the `Func` is set up, but before it's executed, it'll be the value at the time of execution that is used.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the observation that using a `<` operator to feed parameters to an object goes against the expectations of a casual reader, you can use lambdas to represent your functions. For example, [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx), a delegate that does not return a value, may be used like this:

```
Action abs = () => xyz.abc(); // The () => syntax creates a delegate from a piece of code
myTask.AddAction(abs); // Use a named function instead of operator `<`
myTask.AddAction(() => xyz.def()); // You do not need a variable
var result = myTask.Waitfornext();
```

Comment: I know it's not exactly intuitive, but my intention here is to make it so this involves the lesser possible extra syntax

Comment: This answer involves no extra syntax, yours gives `<` a new meaning.